# Error while clicking Manage Content and Structure in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have deployed a feature in my sharepoint 2010 site and that has a list with it. The feature is working fine but when i click Site Settings --> Manage Content and Structure, it leads me to an error page. The error that comes up in the logs is as follows:

**Failed to retrieve the list schema for feature [FEATURE GUID], list template [TEMPLATE]; expected to find it at: ""**

How to resolve this issue, any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list or library somewhere that is based on the list template that was included in that feature.

Go through your lists/libraries and one of them will likely throw an error when you try to access it.

Delete this list or library using PowerShell and you will now be able to access Manage Content and Structure again.

EDIT: Sorry - just re-read your question.  If your list/library based on your feature is working fine then I would not expect an issue with Manage Content and Structure.  Do you have an older version of the list/library that was created in your testing that is causing the issue?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!! one of the lists had some issue, and since the list was not required, I deleted it through powershell and the issue is resolved now.